# wodi64: ocamlopt issues an error

Tags: ocaml

I installed wodi64 on windows 7. When I try to compile a simple hello world program with:

```
ocamlopt -o hello hello.ml
```

I get an error:

```
File "hello.ml", line 1:
Error: Corrupted compilation unit description
C:/wodi64/opt/wodi64/lib/ocaml/std-lib\pervasives.cmx
```

The contents of the hello.ml file are just:

```
print_string "Hello world!\n";;
```

Any idea on how to solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, check that your files are still ok. There are various anti-virus software, that don't like the ocaml compiler and manipulates/remove it's files.

Instructions (from the installed cygwin shell):

```
cd /tmp  # or: wget 'http://wodi.forge.ocamlcore.org/wodi64o.md5sum' -O /tmp/wodi64o.md5sum  
godi_console wget 'http://wodi.forge.ocamlcore.org/wodi64o.md5sum'
cd /opt/wodi64
md5sum -c /tmp/wodi64o.md5sum  
# install md5sum via cygwin's setup, if it's not already installed
```

There can be some mismatches, because configuration files will be updated during operation (e.g /opt/wodi64/lib/ocaml/std-lib/ld.conf, Makefile.config will differ ); but binary files should be identical.

Comment: That might not be the problem I forgot to remove a previously installed OcamlWin. After removing it I installed wodi64 again and now I get: http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/2262/captureeff.png.  Any ideas?